# Getting an application error when setting a range

Tags: vba, range, with-statement

I'm getting an application-defined or objected defined error when trying to set a range.  The first 4 work no problem at all so I'm not sure why the 5th (CD_entireRange) is giving me problems.  (I intentionally left out most of the variables and just put in what I thought was important otherwise its a 500 line code)

```
Dim CD_entireRange As Range

CD_datetimeColumn = 1
CD_weekofColumn = 18
CD_callernumberColumn = 3
CD_talktimeColumn = 8
CD_uniqueduplicateColumn = 14

CD_callendRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
CD_callendCol = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set calldataFile = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calls")

With calldataFile
    Set CD_weekofRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CD_weekofColumn), .Cells(CD_callendRow, CD_weekofColumn))
    Set CD_callernumberRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CD_callernumberColumn), .Cells(CD_callendRow, CD_callernumberColumn))
    Set CD_talktimeRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CD_talktimeColumn), .Cells(CD_callendRow, CD_talktimeColumn))
    Set CD_uniqueduplicateRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CD_uniqueduplicateColumn), .Cells(CD_callendRow, CD_uniqueduplicateColumn))
    Set CD_entireRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CD_datetimeColumn), .Cells(CD_callendRow, CD_callendCol))
End With
```

I'm trying to define the whole range so I can do a sort of the data by specific columns.

When running debug, all my variables are populating correctly. The code is the same as the 4 above it, so again, not sure why I'm receiving the error.

Comment: What is the value of `CD_callendCol` when it throws?

Comment: CD_callendCol is "25"

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Set CD_entireRange = .Range(.Cells(2, CD_datetimeColumn), .Cells(CD_callendRow, CD_datetimeColumn))`? i.e. the 2nd argument to range had a different value for column.

Comment: Run the code and once you hit the error click “debug” button and then type in the Immediate Window (CTRL+G to pop it out) : ?CD_callendCol , press return and see the outcome

Comment: @shahkalpesh I want to set the range for the entire set of data (all rows and columns), so when I sort it in the next steps I'm not sorting and losing necessary data.

Comment: @DisplayName 25

Comment: What is the value of `.Range(.Cells(2, CD_datetimeColumn), .Cells(CD_callendRow, CD_callendCol)).Address`? Does it contain merged cells?

Comment: Then I have no clue. Just for good practice you should move the CD_callendRow and CD_callendCol setting inside the With calldataFile and therefore add necessary dots (i.e. CD_callendCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column , and similarly for CD_callendRow)

Comment: How do I get that value for the address? No merged cells.

Comment: Use Immediate Window and type a question mark followed by the very same code shahkalpesh gave you and press return. But that should give you the same error...

Comment: "Invalid Qualifier"

Comment: Add calldataFile before each dot and retry

Comment: Same runtime error 1004, application defined or object defined error.  I did test on the other 4 and they all displayed the range I am capturing.

Comment: And what’s the value of both CD_datetimeColumn and CD_callendRow returned by Immediate Window upon hitting error?

Comment: Suspecting CD_datetimeColumn is returning some invalid column index (maybe zero?)

Comment: datetimecolumn was pulling back a 1, endrow was pulling back "72".  Realized CD_callendRow and callendCol was set up as a string.  So i guess having 1 string in the range is okay, but having 2 strings throws an error? Problem has been solved I set both to long.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me out. Without your telling me to debug in the window I wouldn't have figured out the problem.  If you want to post an answer telling me to make sure my variables are assigned correctly I can give you credit for this.